# Подключение библиотеки Yandex MapKit на C# xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mapkit

Пишу приложение на Android в MS Visual Studio 2017 использую фреймворк Xamarin, и при подключении библиотеки Yandex MapKit возникли проблемы, в документации указана инструкция, как это сделать на Android Studio, про то как это сделать на С#, нашел очень мало зацепок. Есть кто подключал эту библиотеку? Подскажите!

Comment: Если Xamarin.Android то попробуй забиндить либу. Если Xamarin.Forms то iFroz прав

Comment: На данный момент Xamarin приложения не поддерживаются. FAQ MapKit: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/mapkit/3.x/concepts/faq-docpage/